Theoretical justification for minimizing $KL(q_\phi|p)$ rather than $KL(p|q_\phi)$?
Suppose we have a true but unknown distribution $p$ over some discrete set (i.e. assume no structure or domain knowledge), and a parameterized family of distributions $q_\phi$.
In general it makes sense to me that we would minimize $KL(p|q)$. This denotes the amount of bits of surprise we get, or information we gain, when we figure out that the true distribution is $p$ rather than $q$.
If we minimize $KL(q|p)$ then we are in general making an overconfident estimate: we may in principle assign zero probability to events that are quite likely accordibg to $p$.
Yet in various practical applications (such as variational Bayes) we minimize $KL(q|p)$ and the justification I've generally seen is that this is easier to compute.
But is there a more principled theoretical justification for minimizing $KL(q|p)$ rather than $KL(p|q)$? If we are really interested in $\text{argmin} KL(p|q)$ then even asuming it's not practically computable, why do we specifically pick and $\text{argmin} KL(q|p)$? E.g. If the latter is just an estimator, then aren't there some better estimators that don't have the overconfidence properties of $\text{argmin} KL(q|p)$?

Not an answer, but the KL divergence has the dimension of an area, or length-squared, and therefore gives all kinds of problems when used as a distance. You may benefit from having a peek at our (admittedly long paper): https://www.mdpi.com/2673-9984/5/1/22

@cinch, What is your problem with the letter $\theta$? :P

We usually don't use the subscript symbol $\mathbf{θ}$ for the tractable approximate distribution's variational parameters (btw, subscript symbols under a distribution usually means its parameters, not the r.v. under the said distribution which is actually what you're intending here in your post), we usually use it for true parameters of your model or local latent variables of your model such as in VAEs. Instead other symbols such as $\mathbf{\phi}$ or $\mathbf{\psi}$ are usually used for variational parameters. I also edited the symbol in my answer accordingly and expanded my answer.

TLDR: depending on the details of your approximation problem, you might care about different aspects of a measure of the discrepancy of $p \approx q_\theta$
So we have a probability $p$ and we wish to find the best approximation in some family $q_\theta$. That is a valid and very generic problem that appears in many domains of probility theory, though I am most familiar with Bayesian approximate inference.
We could choose any measure of discrepancy between $p$ and $q_\theta$ to measure the quality of the approximation $p \approx q_\theta$. (NB: some methods do not even use a measure of discrepancy between $p$ and $q_\theta$, such as the Expectation-Propagation algorithm on which I have worked quite a bit).
The critical point, which I think you overlook, is that among that infinity of measures of discrepancy, the $KL(p,q_\theta)$ measure is not that special. The problem $p \approx q_\theta$ is very generic and additional information is needed to further specify exactly:

what aspects of the approximation $p \approx q_\theta$ are more important and which are less: improving the approximation in one direction will make it worse in another direction.
what computational price are we willing to put in to achieve those results.

among other aspects.
So, that leaves us with a huge array of discrepancies. I'll first deal with the comparison of $KL(p,q)$ vs $KL(q,p)$, and I'll list all the other ones at the end:
$KL(p,q)$ has:

an interesting link to entropy as a measure of surprise, which you highlight. I don't have the space to recap this here.
an interesting link to Bayesian inference
a big downside: the expected value under $p$ typically produces a huge computational cost

$KL(q,p)$ has:

the same link to entropy, but the directionality means that it is less interesting
but a big computational upside: the expected value is now under $q$ which leads to a huge computational upside
an interesting link to the evidence lower bound (ELBO): a lower bound on the integral of $p$, if it is unknown, which has major consequences in bayesian inference (for model selection) and statistical physics (lower bound of the entropy of the ensemble)

Finally, on the limit where the approximation is almost exact, these two measures converge:
$$
p \approx q \implies KL(p,q) \approx KL(q,p)
$$
This morally justifies using $KL(q,p)$ as a computationally-simpler alternative to $KL(p,q)$.
Overall, in my own experience in Bayesian statistics, $KL(q,p)$ is superior in practical applications due to its computational aspects. Optimizing $KL(p,q)$ is equivalent to finding a very-high-fidelity sampling approximation of $p$ (typically using markov-chain monte-carlo) which begs the question of why we would want to replace that sampling approximation with a parametric one. Furthermore, I am also convinced that $KL(q,p)$ is better than all alternatives, in the absence of very specific features.
Other measures
For completeness, and to re-emphasize the key point here: there are many choices, here are some other measures:

total variation distance:

it's a metric
clear interepretation: for all intervals, the probability assigned by $p$ and $q_\theta$ is close
downside: computational


wasserstein distances:

it's a metric
clear interpretation: how much effort to "move" samples from $p$ to $q_\theta$
very popular in fundamental probability theory and machine learning in the last decade
high quality bounds from fundamental probability theory


alpha-divergences:

generalization of KL
In my opinion, not that interesting, but it has proven to be a popular point of study in the last decade




"The critical point, which I think you overlook, is that among that infinity of measures of discrepancy, the (,) measure is not that special"
But I did give an argument for a special property, which is: "This denotes the amount of bits of surprise we get, or information we gain, when we figure out that the true distribution is  rather than ". I know you also highlighted this. But THIS is what seems to me to be the criteria we are typically interested in: We want that our model doesn't rule out some actual event that occurs. I will look into your point about ELBO, thank you!

It is special, but not that special. If you are interested in compression and you want to apply's Shanon's optimal coding theorem, then you should care about $KL(p,q)$. In my experience, I've never seen a case where that's relevant, but it could happen. To me, the killer feature of $KL(q,p)$ is the computability, though. Statistics is an applied discipline: if your method cannot run on my computer, what good is it to my statistical practice? And even in analytical arguments, and I've done a few of those, KL(q,p) is better behaved than KL(p,q).

From the definition of $\text{KL}(p|q)$ which is the expectation of the logarithmic difference between the probabilities $p$ and $q$ where the expectation is taken using the probabilities $p$, and if $p$ is the true but unknown parameters' posterior distribution as you specified which means its distribution may often be very complex (skewed, multi--modal, mixture, full covariance, etc) and intractable in practice given very high-dimensional data such as images, then the reverse $\text{KL}(q|p)$ is usually easier to compute since the minimization takes expectations w.r.t. $q$ which is often chosen from a tractable (factorized, mean field) exponential family parameterized by $\mathbf{\psi}$. This KL minimization objective happens to be equivalent to the negative of the evidence lower bound (ELBO) of input data $\mathbf{x}$ which avoids the intractable parameters' true posterior $p(\mathbf{\theta}|\mathbf{x})$ and after reparameterization trick we can use SGD to further optimize and hopefully arrives at a fairly stable and close distribution $q(\mathbf{\theta}|\mathbf{\psi})$.
Important properties of KL as a member of the F-Divergence family are non-negativity, asymmetry, invariant to reparameterizations, satisfying chain rule, data processing inequality, etc. All these nice information-theoretic properties suggest KL as relative entropy (information gain) is a good loss function in variational inference. However, as you correctly noted $\text{KL}(q|p)$ has the unfortunate over-confident mode seeking property when $p$ is the true distribution, but some other approximation method such as Laplace's approximation used in Gaussian Processes may also have same over-confident issue with additional issues such as extreme locality.

The main weaknesses of Laplace's approximation are that it is symmetric around the mode and that it is very local: the entire approximation is derived from properties at a single point of the target density.

Of course there's nothing wrong to consider the other famous integral probability metrics (IPM) family such as Wasserstein distance and maximum mean discrepancy (MMD) as variational objective to handle complex discrepancies between distributions that KL might not capture well. In fact Wasserstein GAN is a widely used robust generative model and it's mean-seeking with better convergence, but since IPM distance is the supremum of expectation differences over a class of functions and Wasserstein distance has to solve the optimal transport problem, therefore it's quite computationally intensive compared to KL and MMD. On the other hand, though MMD can leverage certain kernels instead of ranging over a function class and doesn't require parametric forms of both $p$ and $q$ to become much more computationally efficient, but finding a right MMD kernel for a particular problem can be challenging and MMD being non-parametric requires samples from the true intractable posterior via the prior and likelihood which introduces further approximation errors.
You can also use grid approximation, importance sampling, MCMC or SMC non-variational approximation methods which may be better in terms of accuracy without over-confidence issue, but in general they're much more inefficient or hard to converge especially with big high-dimensional dataset.
